# How does the interpretation of consistent histories fit with the path integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, quantum-interpretations, decoherence

The interpretation of [consistent histories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_histories) states that different histories of a quantum particle have different probabilities, but in fact only one of them happens. If we take the trajectory of the particle as a history, it turns out that only one trajectory is real, that is, the particle passes only one, quite definite trajectory, but we do not know which one. This makes quantum mechanics similar to classical ones. But how does this agree with the path integral, in which it is necessary to take into account the interference effects between different trajectories?

Comment: See Fig. 3 and the surrounding discussion of the paper by Gell-Mann and Hartle: http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~quniverse/papers/qcqm2ndedppt.pdf. Appeared in the Proceedings of the Santa Fe Institute Workshop on Complexity, Entropy,
and the Physics of Information, May 1989 and in the Proceedings of the 3rd International
Symposium on The Foundations of Quantum Mechanics in the Light of New Technology,
Tokyo, Japan, August 1989.

Comment: @Andrew And how can this help answer the question?

Comment: The entire paper is about how to formulate the consistent histories approach using the path integral. The caption of Fig 3 is "The sum-over-histories construction of the decoherence functional." After Eq 6: "The
decoherence functional for coarse-grained histories is obtained from (6) according to the
principle of superposition by summing over all that is not specified by the coarse graining.". The CG histories are the consistent histories. It's a very long story, I might try to write it up if I have time later, but if you want it from the horse's mouth this paper fully answers your question.

Comment: @Andrew I still haven't found an answer, what happens to the alternate trajectories?

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting the consistent histories idea. You end up with *coarse grained* histories that are consistent with all measurements done, but you don't end up with a specific trajectory (which would require you to know both the position and momentum at every time, which would violate the uncertainty principle and would not be a consistent history). I may try to write up an answer later if I have time, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is essentially paraphrasing parts of Sections 3 and 4 of Gell-Mann and Hartle's classic paper on the sum-over-histories point of view on the consistent histories approach given in:

1. *Proceedings of the Santa Fe Institute Workshop on Complexity, Entropy, and the Physics of Information*, May 1989
2. *Proceedings of the 3rd International Symposium on The Foundations of Quantum Mechanics in the Light of New Technology*, Tokyo, Japan, August 1989,
3. Also available on the web as a pdf [here](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Equniverse/papers/qcqm2ndedppt.pdf).

Decoherence plays a key role in any interpretation of quantum mechanics. For example, in the double slit experiment, you will destroy the interference pattern if you measure the slit through which the particle went through. The word "measurement" can be misleading because there doesn't need to be a person involved in this process; a macroscopic object placed near one of the slits which interacts with the electron, will cause the same effect to occur.

The key idea is that without a measurement (or decoherence), the quantum state is a *coherent* superposition $\psi_1 + \psi_2$ (where $\psi_1$ is the probability amplitude for the particle to go through slit 1, and similarly for $\psi_2$). Then the probability to observer the particle on the screen, $P = |\psi_1|^2 + |\psi_2|^2 + 2{\rm Re}(\psi_1^2 \psi_2)$ contains the interference term, and is not simply the sum of the probabilities for the particle to go through either slit, $|\psi_1|^2 + |\psi_2|^2$. On the other hand, if a measurement observes the particle to have gone through slit 1, then the probability is $|\psi_1|^2$, with no interference term. **The outcome of the double slit experiment does not depend on your interpretation of quantum mechanics.** Perhaps you will assign different words to this calculation, but in any approach to quantum mechanics (including the consistent history approach), when no measurement is made with the object going through the slits, there is no way to say which slit the particle went through. (I suppose in a pilot wave theory there are hidden variables that could tell you which slit, but in that case I'm assuming we don't have access to the hidden variables).

What the consistent histories approach does is to build up a set of possible histories that led to the current state of the Universe. In the case of the double slit experiment, we can say there are two histories:

- **History 1** The particle went through slit 1.
- **History 2** The particle went through slit 2.

The **set** of histories $\{{\rm History\ 1}, {\rm History\ 2}\}$ is a set of *consistent histories*, if it is possible to assign probabilities to each history in the set in a consistent way. The exact conditions for when this is possible, for a given set of histories, is described in Gell-Mann and Hartle's paper.

Crucially, a set of histories that is *not* consistent, is to give the value of the position at every point in time (or the value of the momentum, or to take some set of commuting observables and give their values at every point in time). There needs to be some level of *coarse graining* to obtain a set of consistent histories.

In the path integral approach, you

1. First define a set of histories. These are the values of some set of commuting observables at some discrete set of times. Y
2. Further, you *coarse grain* the histories, by allowing for there to be some range of possible values in each observable at each time
3. You assign a probability to a given *coarse-grained* history, by summing the amplitudes for each trajectory in a given history consistent with the constraints laid out by the values (including coarse graining) specified in steps 1 and 2, using the *decoherence functional* defined in their paper.

The set of probabilities you obtain in this way need to satisfy the usual laws of probability. In particular, there cannot be cross terms in which different histories interfere with each other.This puts a minimum bound on how much coarse graining is needed in a given set of histories. In the double slit example, this means that if you see an interference pattern, your coarse graining must be large enough to include the trajectories where the particle passed through both slits.

In the end, you do not end up with a unique trajectory for a quantum particle, but rather a set of possible (coarse-grained) histories for that particles, with a probability you can assign to each history. Note that even picking out one history from the set, you do not know exactly what trajectory the particle took, (a) because of the coarse graining, and (b) because in between the discrete points at which observables are defined, the particle can have any property. Essentially, you have projected the set of *all possible* histories a particle could have taken, onto a smaller (but still infinite) set of consistent, coarse-grained histories.

Comment: We are talking only about one observable. For example, about a coordinate. you may decide to focus your attention on the electron's position at a sequence of (for example) three times t1, t2, t3...

Comment: In this case, in the spirit of consistent histories, you can build trajectories of the type: T1: the electron is at A1 at time t1, at B1 at t2, at C1 at t3 T2: the electron is at A2 at time t1, at B2 at t2, at C2 at t3… Tn: the electron is at An at time t1, at Bn at t2, at Cn at t3 with the sets {A_i}, {B_i}, {C_i} sets of non-overlapping regions of space. Each T story has a certain probability of happening. And one and only one of them occurs in reality. What happens to the rest of the T's?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress I'm not sure I understand your question. The way I understand the consistent histories interpretation (and also following what is on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_histories)), the net result is that you can assign a set of probabilities to different possible histories the particle might have taken. You don't end up with a definite trajectory at discrete times like you are describing (unless you measure the particle's positions at those times).

Comment: In this interpretation, measurement does not play any role, so no, the probabilities relate to quantum events regardless of the measurement.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress OK I'll try to write up an answer today or tomorrow. But measurement does play a role -- for example, in the double slit experiment, if you measure which path the electron took through the slits, you don't see an interference pattern, in any interpretation of quantum mechanics (including consistent histories).

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress I've turned the comments into a more complete answer. The full story is still in the paper, but hopefully this helps. If not, feel free to ask more questions, or else hopefully someone else can arrive to help with what is ailing you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is, I understand correctly that decoherence is a prerequisite for the interpretation of successive histories? A quantum system must decohere with its environment to be able to determine its histories and their probabilities?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress That's basically right. Loosely speaking, I would say you need to coarse grain the histories to the level that they decoherent with each other. If two different histories have decohered, then you can think of them as "separate histories" and the probabilities for different histories add add, without needing interference terms. (Note: you only need this to be approximately true, as discussed in Gell-Mann and Hartle).

Comment: The basic example is the two slit experiment. If you see an interference pattern, the smallest consistent history involves the electron going through both slits. If you don't see an interference pattern, you can have a set of two consistent histories, one where the electron goes through the top, and one where it goes through the bottom.

Comment: On the other hand, if you follow all the degrees of freedom of the environment (which is practically impossible), then you can restore the coherence and the state of superposition. However, almost everything in the universe from the very beginning decohered with its environment, so we got one semiclassical history out of an infinite number of possible ones (although if it were possible to start all over again, the history would be different, since this is also probabilistic).

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Right, I think this is related to the point that Gell-Mann and Hartle make that the overlaps between decoherent histories only need to be *approximately* zero. The give the example that, classically, the sun might not rise tomorrow because maybe there's a neutron star on a collision course with Earth travelling near the speed of light that will hit us tomorrow. But in practice we treat the probability of this and similar extremely unlikely events as if they were zero. Similarly as a practical matter you can ignore tiny residual correlations after decoherence.

Comment: By the way, Vilenkin and Aguirra found out that if the Universe is infinite, then all possible consistent quasi-classical histories that can happen in a region the size of our cosmological horizon will take place in it. Based on the interpretation of consistent histories, they calculated the number of possible histories from the big bang to 14 billion years later. It turned out a finite number, 10^10^150 consistent histories, each with its own probability.